# How to implement href in jgrowl?

Tags: jquery, jgrowl

How can i include a link in jgrowl notification box so that it is clickable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried it? [This](http://jsfiddle.net/cLReA/) seems to work just fine for me?

```
$.jGrowl('<a href="http://www.google.com">Link</a> working?');
```